# How to return empty|null collection in linq to sql if entity (collection parent) is null

Tags: c#, sql, linq, collections, entity

I have an easy linq to sql query that has some expression:

```
from entity in entities
let types = entity.SubEntity != null ? entity.SubEntity.Items.Select(x => x.Type) : null
select new { ... }
```

where 'types' is list of strings.

In final I have an error 
`An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.`

I suppose that SQL can't create empty collection or return null.

What is correct solution?

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: Stacktrace is too long but initital: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski do you need more details?

Comment: There should be a second error message for the inner exception.  Please include that in your question and not in the comments.